# How to add vertical and horizontal lines in an array

Tags: arrays, line, vertical

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \left( \begin{array}{cccccccc|cccccccc}
    6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 3 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 6 
    \end{array}\right) 
    \]
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Is there any idea how to get this one:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `blkarray` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \[ \aboverulesep=0pt \belowrulesep=0pt
    \begin{pmatrix} \begin{blockarray}{@{}*{8}{c}|*{8}{c}@{}}
        \begin{block}{*{6}{c}|cc|*{8}{c}}
        6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \cmidrule{1-8}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{block}
    \midrule
        \begin{block}{*{8}{c}|*{6}{c}|cc}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
        \cmidrule{9-16}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 &-3 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 6 \\[-2ex]
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}\end{pmatrix}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environement is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, row and columns. You can use those nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz after the construction of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\begin{document}
    \[
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{16}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin]
    6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 3 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 6 
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw [shorten > = 2pt] (7-|1) -- (7-|9) ;
       \draw [shorten > = 2pt] (1-|7) -- (9-|7) ;
       \draw (9-|1) -- (9-|last) (1-|9) -- (last-|9) ;
       \draw [shorten < = 2pt] (15-|9) -- (15-|last) ;
       \draw [shorten < = 2pt] (9-|15) -- (last-|15) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]